# Is a Terminal Services CAL included in a thin client with Windows XP Embedded

Tags: terminal-server, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Suppose you buy a thin client that you wish to use for citrix. Does the thin client include a TS cal. Is this standard or do I have to buy them seperately?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to buy TS/RDS CALs separately, unless you are explicitly aware that you are buying such licensing together with the device.